# Curl --user and -d equivalent in Java

Tags: java, curl

I would like to add some entries in our database and it requires some authentication and I would like to use Java and not Curl to do this. The API only allows me to do this set of commands to access the database.

curl --user user@someemail.com:password *https://somewebsite.com/api/*

To add new entries
curl -d "title=Title&address=address" *https://somewebsite.com/api/new*

To delete entries
curl -X DELETE *https://somewebsite.com/api/product/productid*

Is there a library in Java that can perform this kind of operation?

Answer (score -1):

use HttpClient in java to achieve the same thing.

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Answer (score -1):

[Apache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/) is the first one that comes to mind, and probably the most rhobust.

You can search for "Java REST API" and you'll get lots of options.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710199/which-is-the-best-java-rest-api-restlet-or-jersey is another SO question addressing it.

Comment: Hi, can you help me on this thread http://bit.ly/nLZRRk. I'm having problem with authentication I keep getting access denied but when I try to use cURL it was ok.